# PRISM + Unity - Issue loading dynamic set of modules

Tags: .net, wpf, prism, unity-container

I keep getting the error below, and have been unable to figure it out.  I am wondering if anyone can assist.

**Error:**
Failed to load type for module MyExternalAssembly.MyNamespace.MyModule.

If this error occurred when using MEF in a Silverlight application, please ensure that the CopyLocal property of the reference to the MefExtensions assembly is set to true in the main application/shell and false in all other assemblies.

Error was: Unable to retrieve the module type MyExternalAssembly.MyNamespace.MyModule, MyExternalAssembly.MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null from the loaded assemblies.  You may need to specify a more fully-qualified type name..

**Code:**

Load Screen (loads modules, stores Assembly reference for various uses)

```
    string[] dynamicLibraries = Directory.GetFiles(pluginDirectory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    // Parse through the DLL's and look for types that implement "IModule".
    foreach (string file in dynamicLibraries)
    {
        // Get the plugin assembly information.
        Assembly plugin = Assembly.LoadFile(file);

        // Get all types that are exported for plugins.
        IEnumerable<Type> modules = plugin.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(IModule).IsAssignableFrom(t));

        if (modules.Count() > 0)
        {
            ApplicationState.Instance.Plugins.Add(plugin, modules);
        }
    }
```

Here is the ConfigureModuleCatelog Method

```
protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

    ModuleCatalog catalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;

    foreach (var assembly in ApplicationState.Instance.Plugins)
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.Value)
        {
            this.ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo
            {
                ModuleName = type.FullName,
                ModuleType = type.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                Ref = new Uri(assembly.Key.Location, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsoluteUri,
                InitializationMode = InitializationMode.WhenAvailable
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I need a way to maintain/use this "Plugin" dictionary and get Modularization to wprk properly.  And ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused. You say Unity but then your code is using MEF types. And if you're using MEF, why on Earth are you manually finding `IModule` implementations - you should be using MEF to do the dynamic resolution for you.

Comment: The bootstraper inherits from UnityBootstraper.  I am manually finding IModule's because I have a requirement to report loaded modules on a loading screen.  The whole control aspect is because I need to load modules into an Avalon Dock (DockableContent), and the only way I can see to do that is if I wrap the modules and manually load them with a DockableContent base.

In the end, I probably need to do a little more research, but just trying to learn and get things going.  I'll take any suggestions to where you think I am going wrong.

Comment: Also if you are referring to the Error to determine the "MEF Type" it says "If this error occurred when using MEF", not the "If".  I am far from a Prism/Unity/MEF master, maybe you can tell me what types you see that are MEF?

Comment: ModuleCatalog is a MEF type, which is why I'm confused. Any reason you're using Unity over MEF?

Comment: No reason, I was told to use Unity.  ModuleCatalog looks like it's a prism type.  As an update, this code sorta works if I strong name the plugin assembly.  But I do get another error "An exception occurred while creating a region with name 'MainRegion'. The exception was: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The IRegionAdapter for the type System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl is not registered in the region adapter mappings. You can register an IRegionAdapter for this control by overriding the ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings method in the bootstrapper."